# how to use jqgrid for mobile browser

Tags: mobile, jqgrid

we are working on application for converting web application into mobile app. i need to use jqgrid for showing data in view page. it shows some problem of column width size. we tried to resize that in css , but column size and column header size is not matching. do anyone have any idea of how to use jqgrid in mobile or any other good alternative for mobile,. here is code that we tried :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function (){ 
        jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid({ 
            url:"${customerListUrl}", 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames:['<fmt:message key="active"/>','<fmt:message key="group"/>','<fmt:message key="name"/>', '<fmt:message key="customer.code"/>','<fmt:message 

key="email"/>','<fmt:message key="organisation"/>','<fmt:message key="distribution.channel"/>','<fmt:message key="salesoffice"/>','<fmt:message key="unit"/>'], 
            colModel:[  
                    {name:'active',index:'active', width:0,formatter:'checkbox',stype:'select', sortable:false,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']},editoptions:

{value:"true:Yes;false:No"}},
                    {name:'group',index:'group', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,stype:'select',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']},editoptions:{value:":All;DE:Channel 

sales;DC:Direct consumer"}},
                   {name:'name',index:'name', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}}, 
                   {name:'code',index:'code', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}},
                   {name:'email',index:'email', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,search:false,editable:true,editoptions:{size:60},formoptions:{ rowpos:1, label: "Email", 

elmprefix:"(*)"},editrules:{required:true,email:true}},
                   {name:'org',index:'org', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{searchhidden:true,sopt:['eq']}},
                   {name:'channel',index:'channel', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{searchhidden:true,sopt:['eq']}},
                   {name:'salesOffice',index:'salesOffice', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{searchhidden:true,sopt:['eq']}},
                   {name:'unit',index:'unit', width:0, align:"left", sortable:false,searchoptions:{searchhidden:true,sopt:['eq']}}
                   ],
            rowNum:15, 
            autowidth: true, 
            rowList:[15,30],
            pager: jQuery('#customerpager'), 
            sortname: 'name', 
            viewrecords: true, 
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: 300,
            caption:'<fmt:message key="customer"/>',
            loadError : function(xhr, st, str){
                    $('#griderrdialog').dialog('open');
                }
        }); 

        jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('hideCol',["org","channel","salesOffice","unit","active","group"]); 

        jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('navGrid','#customerpager',
                {
                    edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true
                },
                {}, // edit options
                {}, // add options
                {}, //del options
                {multipleSearch:true,closeAfterSearch:true} // search options
            ).navButtonAdd("#customerpager",{ caption:"", buttonicon:"ui-icon-document",
                            onClickButton: function(row_id){ 

                                      var id = jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
                                       if (id) { 
                                        var ret = jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('getRowData',id); 

                                         formObject = document.f1;

                                         jQuery("#detail").val(id);
                                         formObject.submit();
                                       } else { 
                                           $('#rownotseldialog').dialog('open');
                                       }
                            }, 
                            position:"first", title:'${actionheader}'
             });
        jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#customerpager',{ 
                        caption: "", 
                        title: "Reorder Columns", 
                        onClickButton : function (){ 
                                        jQuery("#customerList").jqGrid('columnChooser'); 
                                        } 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently only restricted support of jQuery Mobile in jqGrid. How you can see from [the thread](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/add-support-for-jq-mobile/) support of jQuery Mobile will be soon implemented in jqGrid. See the corresponding demo from trirand [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/mobile/).

Comment: How do we incorporate jqgrid mobile in the current jqgrid(free jqgrid 5.0.1) implementation.What are the features not supported in mobile jqgrid?Can you please provide link to the documentation of jqgrid mobile?

Comment: @johndoe: First of all, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the name of the product (the for of jqGrid), which I develop starting with the end of 2014. It's current version is 4.13.5. I use 4.x.y as the version to stress backword compatibility to jqGrid 4.x (up to 4.7). One can use free jqGrid completely free of charge. 5.0.1 is the version of Guriddo jqGrid JS, which **can't be used for free** (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)).

Comment: @johndoe: There are no special mobile version of free jqGrid. The only mobile friendly feature is support of Bootstrap (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)) and support of responsive classes like `"hidden-xs"` http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/8/. Try to resize the window on the demo. About Guriddo jqGrid Mobile and it's features and prices look [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=119). I personally don't see that one should use jqGrid in case of displaying one column only.